# Is a friend function that overloads an insertion operator meant to be declared & defined in the base class or in each derived class?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, polymorphism, operator-overloading

For this program, I'm tasked with parsing an input file and then outputting it in several ways. One of the ways it's meant to be output is by recombining the information from the derived classes and the necessary information from the base class into a string. I'm required to do this using stringstream and by overloading the insertion operator. My textbook says to declare the friend function in the base class and a stringstream toString() func in each derived class and the base class. However, when I try to loop through a vector of pointers to each class object, it just gives me a string of numbers (which I suspect is an address?) Please help. I will include all the necessary code and current output as well as expected output.

```
#include "university.h"
#include "snap.h"
#include "csg.h"
#include "cdh.h"
#include "cr.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    vector<University*> allDataObjects;

    cout << "Input file: " << argv[1] << endl;
    ifstream in(argv[1]);
    if (!in)
    {
        cerr << "Unable to open " << argv[1] << " for input";
        return 2;
    }
    cout << "Output file: " << argv[2] << endl;
    ofstream out(argv[2]);
    if (!out)
    {
        in.close();
        cerr << "Unable to open " << argv[2] << " for output";
        return 3;
    }

    for (string currLine; getline(in, currLine);) {

        if ("snap(" == currLine.substr(0, 5)) { // Ex. snap(12345,Charlie Brown,Manager,555-1234).
            cout << currLine << endl;

            string stuID = currLine.substr(5, currLine.find(',') - 5);
            currLine = currLine.substr(currLine.find(',') + 1);
            string stuName = currLine.substr(0, currLine.find(','));
            currLine = currLine.substr(currLine.find(',') + 1);
            string stuAddress = currLine.substr(0, currLine.find(','));
            currLine = currLine.substr(currLine.find(',') + 1);
            string stuPhone = currLine.substr(0, currLine.find(')'));

            allDataObjects.push_back(new Snap(stuID, stuName, stuAddress, stuPhone));
        }
    ...
    }
    cout << endl << "Vectors: " << endl;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < allDataObjects.size(); i++) {
        cout << allDataObjects[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
};
```

Base class:

```
#ifndef UNIVERSITY_H
#define UNIVERSITY_H

#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

class University {
public:
    University(string stuID = "", string courseNew = "") { studentID = stuID; courseName = courseNew; }
    ~University() = default;

    string ToString() { 
        ostringstream id;
        id << courseName << studentID;
        return id.str(); 
    }
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, University& uni) {
        os << uni.ToString();
        return os;
    }   
private:
    string studentID;
    string courseName;
};
#endif
```

Derived class:

```
#ifndef SNAP_H
#define SNAP_H

#include "university.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

class Snap : public University { // studentID, studentName, studentAddress, studentPhone
public:
    Snap(const string& stuID, string stuName, string stuAddress, string stuPhone) :
        University(stuID), studentName(stuName), studentAddress(stuAddress), studentPhone(studentPhone) {}
private:
    string studentName;
    string studentAddress;
    string studentPhone;
    string ToString() {
        ostringstream out;
        out << "snap(" << University::ToString() << "," << studentName << "," << studentAddress << "," << 
    studentPhone << ")";
        return out.str();
    };
};
```

Current Output -> Expected Output

```
Input Strings:                                              Input Strings:
snap(12345,Charlie Brown,Manager,555-1234).     ->          snap(12345,Charlie Brown,Manager,555-1234).
snap(67890,Lucy,Right Field,555-5678).                      snap(67890,Lucy,Right Field,555-5678).
...                                                         ...
                                                ->
Vectors:                                                    Vectors:
00BFF2F0                                                    snap(12345,Charlie Brown,Manager,555-1234)
00C03710                                        ->          snap(67890,Lucy,Right Field,555-5678)
...
```

Literally I'm just supposed to output the exact same line (minus a period), but using polymorphism and an overloaded operator. I don't get any errors so it's clearly a logic issue.
Thank you.

Comment: It looks like you are streaming elements of `allDataObjects`. Do you recall the type of elements of `allDataObjects` and perhaps why they would be addresses?

Comment: @JaMiT I think that they are pointers to derived class objects. But as you mention that, am I failing to actually create the objects in the first place?

Comment: Correct, they are pointers. You streamed those pointers and got addresses, which makes sense since pointers store addresses. Since you want to instead stream the objects stored at those addresses, how does one convert a pointer to the thing to which it points? (I believe that part of your code is off by only one character.)

Comment: @JaMiT Using pass by reference? The & symbol?

Comment: Other way around. The reference operator takes an object and returns a pointer. The de-reference operator takes a pointer and returns the object. Try streaming `*allDataObjects[i]`.

Comment: @JaMiT So that worked a little better, instead of giving the pointer it gave only the base class object variables, left out the derived class.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207010/discussion-between-burningyeti-and-jamit).